# Melave d'Malka on Motze Shabbos which falls on Yom Tov eve

Tags: yom-tov, motzei-shabbos, melave-malka

Is there an obligation to have *melave d'malka* on *Motzei Shabbos* which falls on *Yom Tov*?

Although there is anyways an obligation to have a *Yom Tov* meal, there are still some possible ramifications:

- *Melave D'Malka* for women who are *makpid* on *Melave DMalka*, but according to many *poskim* are not obligated in Seudas Yom Tov (see *Shu"t R' Akiva Eiger* §1).
- Should one add an extra food item for *Melava DMalka*? (Similar to the ruling of the Mishne Beruro (419.2) writes that when Rosh Chodesh falls on Shabbos, '*medakdekim*' should add an extra food item to be recognizably *lkovod Rosh Chodesh*.)
- Does one need to have specific intent when eating the Yom Tov *seuda* to discharge his obligation for *Melave D'Malka*? Although *Melave Dmalka* generally does not require specific intent [For two reasons: 1) We *pasken* that *mitzvos drabbanan ein tzrichos kevana* (intent is not required), 2) According to many *poskim* *mitzvos shel achila einon tzrichos kevana*], the Rishonim say that when one has specific intent for one obligation, that automatically constitutes *kavana hefchis* (intent NOT to discharge) for any other obligation. Therefore, when one eats Seudas Yom Tov, one will not be *yotzei* *melava dmalka* unless he has specific intent.

Comment: The fact that I considered *melave dmalka* as a *mitzva d'achila* (as a reason it would not require *kavana*) is up for debate: One could suggest that it isn't a mitzva to *eat* (like matza), but rather *kovod shabbos* requires a *seuda* - to have a meal.

Comment: See also Derech Sicha (R' Chaim Kanievsky) p. 271, who writes that there is an obligation, but one can discharge it with *seudas yom tov*. He writes that it is a *mitzva dachila* and therefore does not require *kavana*. He doesn't seem to agree that *kavana* for *seudas yom tov* detracts from this *kavana*

Comment: I would think that the Minhag of Melave Malka should be overridden by the Mitzvah of Seudas Yom Tov.

Comment: @DonielF That’s what the OP thought too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R' Chaim P'lagi (הגדה של פסח, חיים לראש) writes that if Pesach falls on Sunday, one should add something in the *seuda* during the *seder* for *melave dmalka*.

Seemingly, there is an obligation to have *Melave dMalka* even when Motzei Shabbos coincides with Yom Tov, and (at least) the second ramification mentioned in the question is true.

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Moshe Mordechai Karp, Chief Rabbi Of Kiryat Sefer in Israel, discusses this in his book on the laws of Sefirah and Shavuos. On page 121 (#23), he writes that there is no obligation to have any intent for Melavah Malka when Motzei Shabbos falls on YomTov.

Footnote 48 gives further explanation:

> 48 . כ״נ פשוט דרק בחול תיקנו סעודה ללוות המלך שלא לצאת משבת לחול , אבל י " ט שחל במוצ " ש הוא עצמו מלוה למלך , ועי ' פסחים קג . והוצרכתי לזה לפי שראיתי למי שכ ' לכוון למצות מלוה מלכה , ולא מצאתי לזה שום יסוד בפו ' .