# May Jews combine the Purim meal with melave malkah

Tags: halacha, purim, orach-chaim, motzei-shabbos, melave-malka

This year, purim falls out on Motzai Shabbat. My question is, is it permitted in Halacha for Jews to combine the melavah malka meal with the purim Seudah? Or no, if they want to fulfill both mitzvot should they be eaten separately?

Comment: The Purim meal is eaten by day. Not in the evening.

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104634/759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be noted, if one eats the seuda on the night of the 14th, they have not fulfilled their obligation to eat a seuda, so the question doesn't start in that regard.
Having said that, one should also eat a somewhat larger seuda at night, so we can look into that aspect.
See Shulchan Aruch 695

> סעודת פורים שעשאה בלילה לא יצא ידי חובתו. הגה: ומכל מקום גם בלילה ישמח וירבה קצת בסעודה. (תשובת מהרי''ב):

And see there, Mishna Berurah #3, where addresses a year when the 14th is Motzai Shabbos. He doesn't seem to be bothered that it is also a melave malka.

> וירבה קצת בסעודה - ואפילו כשחל הי"ד במוצאי שבת דעשה סעודה חשובה בסעודה שלישית מ"מ צריך להרבות קצת בלילה לכבוד פורים אך אינה סעודה כמו למחר דשם צריך להרבות יותר.